# 302 Moved Temporarily or 301?

Tags: seo, redirects, http-headers, 302-redirect

HTTP status code checker tool shows `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily` for the home page URL `http://someurl.com` (just a *namesake* URL). Also, this URL opens up `http://www.someurl.com/general/index`.

As you can see, a `no-www` URL to a `www` URL redirect is happening.

My questions are:

1. **Is a 302 redirect acceptable** for the home page?
2. Will this affect the site showing up in **search results** in anyway?
3. Isn't redirection to `/general/index` a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect `example.com` => `www.example.com` (or vice versa), then use a 301. If you want to redirect the root URL to an internal path, `www.example.com` => `www.example.com/general/index` then use a 302.

The internal redirection isn't necessary a bad practice. Sometimes CMS impose this redirect because the CMS package needs to be installed in subfolders and/or generates a custom homepage URL.

Comment: If a CMS requires redirection to a sub-path it's badly designed IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the answers to your question:

1. In this case you should use a 301 (permanent redirect) because this is a definitive change of the behavior of that URL
2. This will not affect your website in anyway. The search engine will still be able to index your pages in the right way. They, of course, will update your old homepage with the new one (`/general/index`)
3. It's not a bad practice but in my opinion you should change this behavios simply using an *.htaccess*. So the incoming request to the old index will be served by the new homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do 302 redirect for your home page. I would prefer that you do a 301 redirect.

You can also use Google Webmaster Tools to set up your preferred domain.